# Check for Process if Same is Running

Tags: shell-script, scripting, process

Is there a script or a way in linux that when I try to execute a shell script/process, if the same is running, it will prompt that same is running and will exit otherwise it will continue.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this one liner to do what you want:

```
$ pgrep script.bash && echo "already running" || ( ./script.bash & )
```

#### Example

Say I had this script:

```
$ cat script.bash 
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello World"
sleep 10
```

If we use our one liner:

```
$ pgrep script.bash && echo "already running" || ( ./script.bash & )
Hello World
$
```

We run it again:

```
$ pgrep script.bash && echo "already running" || ( ./script.bash & )
10197
already running
$
```

Waiting 10 seconds and running it again, it again works:

```
$ pgrep script.bash && echo "already running" || ( ./script.bash & )
Hello World
$
```

Comment: Also, the name of the bash script is it's unique identifier. So if the script file is renamed the above method wont work. Duh?

Comment: That should be obvious, I thought????

Comment: Well, to me and you, yes it is.  But I left this comment for the novice users.

Comment: @BleedingFingers - Ha. That makes more sense...nevermind 8-)

Comment: There are a number of concerns with using `pgrep` for tasks like this. Keep in mind that `pgrep script` will also return processes named *somescriptname*. There are additional options such as `-f` and `-x` but these have practical drawbacks. If you run `pgrep script` from within `script`, it will always echo "already running". It can be fairly straightforward if you are running pgrep from a caller script, but the same cannot be said for running pgrep from within a script.

Answer (score 6):

**Note this answer is orientated toward a self checking script, for manually checking if a process is running before attempting to run it from the command line, see [slm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117651/48083).**

The easiest way is to use `pgrep` if it is available:

```
if pgrep "$0" >/dev/null
then
  echo "$0 is already running" 2>&1
  exit 1
fi
```

If not, you can use a combination of `ps` and `grep`:

```
if ps -Ao comm | grep -q "^$0\$"
then
  echo "$0 is already running" 2>&1
  exit 1
fi
```

---

It is more robust to use a lock file though as it is always possible that the process is running under a different name. Here is an example using `flock`:

```
lockfile=/var/lock/mprog
{
  if ! flock -n 9
  then
    echo "Unable to lock $lockfile, exiting" 2>&1
    exit 1
  fi

  # do stuff here

} 9>"$lockfile"
```

Comment: The file locking approach is much better than any of the other approaches posted, since it avoids a race condition.  The others do not.

Comment: What happens if the script crashes? Will the lock be removed?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that. I prefer that the script prevents from running same copies by itself by storing it's pid.

One convenient method is `pidof`

```
$ pidof -x /bin/yourscript || /bin/yourscript
```

with ps

```
$ ps aux|grep -q /bin/yourscript || /bin/yourscript
```

self checking

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME=$(basename $0)

if ps -p `cat /var/run/$NAME".pid` >/dev/null 2>&1; then
   echo "script already running"
   exit 1
fi

echo $$ > /var/run/$NAME".pid"

...
rm /var/run/$NAME".pid"
```

there are a lot of other scripts. For example [solo](http://timkay.com/solo/)

Comment: Only problem with the pid file approach is that if the script finishes prematurely (eg is killed) and can't delete the file, there is always the chance that a completely different process will have the stored pid next time the script runs.

Comment: Right. Therefore this is only the light version. :-) However there are still a lot of scripts they do not check even this and stop only if the pidfile exists.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how portable the various lock file approaches are. In some cases this may be the best option.

Comment: @Graeme: Wise spoken.

Comment: All of these approaches have a race condition.

Comment: @Graeme Just an FYI that your concern regarding lockfile cleanup is valid and that it is indeed impossible to plan for *every* contingency. However, there is a simple way to handle this most of the time: `trap`. Once you know what the name of lockfile will be, run `trap 'rm -rf "$lockfile"' EXIT`. Please note however that nothing can catch SIGKILL, trap included.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that doing something like this *reliably* in Unix in general is impossible was one of the things that sparked off the development of tools like [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) (it uses the Linux-specific cgroups feature to cage processes, and thus keeping them under tight control, including restarting as needed). You can cobble something together using ps(1) or pgrep(1), stashing away a PID in a file and checking, and so on. But all of those are subject to races, cheating, or plain mistakes.

You should go over your needs and see how critical it is if it goes awry, how repetitive this is (is it worth automating, or is it something done on and off?), how interesting a target it is for potential attackers, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this. The easiest solution I found was to check for a check_running.txt file in the directory. if the file exists; then the script is already running, Then initialize the file, and at the end of your script rm the file from the directory. This way as long as the file is in the directory, the script is running.

```
if [[ -f check_running.txt ]]; then 
  echo "already running"
  exit 
fi

touch check_running.txt 
...
...
...
rm check_running.txt
```

I believe this can be implemented with just a flag variable too.

Comment: Using a directory is "more atomic". `mkdir` will fail if the directory exists, which we can use as a test. Between the `-f` test and `touch`, there is an interval where the process _thinks_ it can run `touch` but another instance of the script may do the same at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Using a lock directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

lockdir=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/mylock

if ! mkdir "$lockdir" 2>/dev/null; then
    exit 1
fi

trap 'rmdir "$lockdir" 2>/dev/null' EXIT HUP INT TERM

# The rest of code goes here.
```

Using a lock directory is safer than using a lock file. If using a file, you would have to do a separate test for the existence of the file before creating it. In the interval between those two operations, another instance of the script may try to do the same. The `mkdir` utility provides an atomic "create-if-not-exist" operation.

Caveat: The code above does not detect whether the script is already running, but whether the lock directory exists. If the script terminates abnormally, e.g. through being killed by `SIGKILL`, the lock directory will be left behind, and no new instances of the script would be able to start.

---

The following variation tries to detect a lock directory that has been left behind by an abnormally terminated script.  It only *detects* the left-over lock, but does not try to do any cleaning up (this would introduce new race-conditions).

```
#!/bin/sh

lockdir=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/mylock

if { read pid <"$lockdir/pid" && ! kill -0 "$pid"; } 2>/dev/null then
    printf 'Detected left-over lock "%s"\n' "$lockdir" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if ! mkdir "$lockdir" 2>/dev/null; then
    echo 'Could not get lock' >&2
    exit 1
fi

printf '%d\n' "$$" >"$lockdir/pid"

trap '{ rm "$lockdir/pid" && rmdir "$lockdir"; } 2>/dev/null' EXIT HUP INT TERM

# The rest of code goes here.
```

The command `! kill -0 "$pid"` will be true if `$pid` does not refer to a process ID that is currently allocated to a running process.