# lockfile-progs utilities usage

Tags: bash, debian, ubuntu

**There is [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117643/check-for-process-if-same-is-running) that is related, but it is actually different, because I'm asking why the behavior of lockfile-create & lockfile-touch is different to the current contents of the manual page.**

I have this script to learn and understand the lockfile-progs utilities. I've tested it and works good. But, I find the lines related to lockfile-touch unnecessary. My script only needs to launch one xterm instance on one machine per user. I will do the right thing removing the lockfile-touch lines? Someone knows if I will have some trouble with the modified script?

```
#!/bin/bash

function atexit {
    kill $LOCKFILE_TOUCH_PID
    lockfile-remove $DOTLOCK_FILENAME
    echo atexit!
    exit
}

DOTLOCK_FILENAME=/tmp/xterm-one-instance-$UID
lockfile-create --retry 0 --use-pid $DOTLOCK_FILENAME || exit

lockfile-touch $DOTLOCK_FILENAME & LOCKFILE_TOUCH_PID=$!
echo lockfile-touch running, PID=$LOCKFILE_TOUCH_PID

trap atexit EXIT HUP INT TERM
xterm
```

My modified script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function atexit {
    lockfile-remove $DOTLOCK_FILENAME
    echo atexit!
    exit
}

DOTLOCK_FILENAME=/tmp/xterm-one-instance-$UID
lockfile-create --retry 0 --use-pid $DOTLOCK_FILENAME || exit

trap atexit EXIT HUP INT TERM
xterm
```

still prevents another xterm instance after 5m 33s. I found this behavior confusing after reading in the manual page that I need touch the lock file every five minutes.

Comment: The man page says you have to touch the lock file every five minutes.  Where are you doing that?

Comment: Look at [flock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html). It seems closer your needs.

Comment: related - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117643/check-for-process-if-same-is-running/117648#117648

Comment: @Mikel, my script name is `xterm-one-instance` and I've modified my script commenting the lockfile-touch related lines. I've run `./xterm-one-instance & sleep 333; ./xterm-one-instance` and the lock still works after 5m 33s. I'm confused about this behavior and the information on the manual page. Thanks @Mikel & @Graeme for your suggestions.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong solution. You want a lock, so use `flock` as  @Mikei suggested. If you want to lock a file, the use `lockfile-*` it will timeout after 5 mins if something goes wrong (when either `lockfile-remove` or `lockfile-touch` are not called).

Comment: @XTian you are wrong. The manual page is incomplete. You can verify that in the _liblockfile_ source code, see the answer. `lockfile-create` doesn't timeout after five minutes with the `--use-pid` option. You can test that with `./xterm-one-instance & sleep 333; ./xterm-one-instance`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source says:

```
 *  Without a pid in the lockfile, the lock
 *  is valid if it is newer than 5 mins.
```

So it seems you don't need `lockfile-touch` if you are using the `--use-pid` option.