# Check if the script was already run in the current shell session

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, subshell

I have a script that's interactive if started without arguments, and I'd like it to print an ASCII-art logo the first time it's run in the current shell session. Is this possible to detect somehow?

I forgot to mention that I'd like to do it without writing to helper files. Is it possible to detect it inside the shell? Is there some log of processes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check for Process if Same is Running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117643/check-for-process-if-same-is-running)

Comment: No, that checks if the script is already running before launching it. I'm interested in whether it ran at any time during the current shell session.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 ways:

---

One, your script attempts to create a file with the parent shell's PID in the name

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
already_run_file=/tmp/${0##*/}.$PPID
if [[ ! -f $already_run_file ]]; then
    echo "ascii art"
    touch "$already_run_file"
fi
...
```

Drawback: those files would have to be cleaned up... somehow.

---

Two: create a wrapper function for the script. Suppose your program is called `myscript`, then if an environment variable does not exist, add a "-A" option to the program invocation:

```bsh
myscript() {
    if [[ ! -v MYSCRIPT_HAS_RUN ]]; then
        export MYSCRIPT_HAS_RUN=$(printf '%(%s)T' -1)  # timestamp
        set -- -A "$@"
    fi
    command myscript "$@"
}
```

And, add to `myscript`:

```bsh
while getopts :A opt; do
    [[ $opt == A ]] && echo "$ascii_art"
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Or, print the ASCII art from the function.

Comment: Where would I put the wrapper function?

Comment: Typically, ~/.bashrc is the place for them.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't really work for me, because I'd like the script to be standalone. Also, messing about with helper files is too much of a pain for the trivial functionality I'm trying to add. I don't suppose bash keeps some log of processes?

Comment: Nope. You need to keep some marker that you've run that program _for that bash process_.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way, using the date of a flag file

```
#!/bin/bash
me="${0##*/}"
typeset -i first=0
flag="/tmp/$USER.$me.run"
[[ -f "$flag" ]] || touch --date=yesterday "$flag"
if [ $(date "+%d") -ne $(date "+%d" -r "$flag") ] ;then
    first=1
fi
```

At the end, `$first` is `1` for the first execution ever, and first execution daily, or `0` if not. The flag file is named "Username.Scriptname" to avoid interference.